# Create Tempview from sql query

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark

```
df_sales = spark.sql(
"SELECT \
s.TRANS_DT, \
s.STORE_KEY, \
s.PROD_KEY, \
s.SALES_QTY
FROM sales s \
JOIN inventory i ON s.cal_dt=i.cal_dt and s.store_key=i.store_key and s.prod_key=i.prod_key;"
)
```

I created sql query from 2 tempview (inventory and sales). How to convert df_sales sql query to tempview again and I can create a new SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView.html) and you can write your own code as follows:

```py
spark.sql(
"""
SELECT
    s.TRANS_DT,
    s.STORE_KEY,
    s.PROD_KEY,
    s.SALES_QTY
FROM sales s
JOIN inventory i ON s.cal_dt=i.cal_dt and s.store_key=i.store_key and s.prod_key=i.prod_key;
"""
).createOrReplaceTempView("tmpViewName")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).